# How to use InstallForge environment variables to set registry values

Tags: windows, installation, install-forge

I would like to use %IF_INSTALLPATH% to set a Registry value with InstallForge, but it doesn't resolve the variable.  So the registry value created is "%IF_INSTALLPATH%\bin" instead of "C:\MyApp\bin".

How can I use %IF_INSTALLPATH% in setting a registry value?